# Вывод списка дат между двумя датами с использованием jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ui, datepicker

Мне нужно вывести список дат между двумя заданными датами. Для этого я использую `jQuery UI Datepicker`. Проблема в том, что когда я диапазон дат во второй раз, предыдущий список остаётся, а новый выводится под ним.

**Например, я выбираю:**

```
01/04/2016 — 05/04/2016 и получаю такой результат:
01/04/2016
02/04/2016
03/04/2016
04/04/2016
05/04/2016.
```

Здесь всё нормально. Однако когда я опять выбираю диапазон дат с `02/04/2016` по `07/04/2016`,

**я уже получаю:**

```
01/04/2016
02/04/2016
03/04/2016
04/04/2016
05/04/2016
02/04/2016
03/04/2016
04/04/2016
05/04/2016
02/04/2016
03/04/2016
04/04/2016
05/04/2016
06/04/2016
07/04/2016
```

**вместо**:

```
02/04/2016
03/04/2016
04/04/2016
05/04/2016
06/04/2016
07/04/2016
```

. Чтобы этого не происходило, я вынужден перезагружать страницу, что не очень удобно. Как можно избавиться от этой проблемы и сделать так, чтобы выводились нужные даты?
Ниже код:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      //defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      //defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });

<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" onchange="dtrange()">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" onchange="dtrange()">
<p id="result" onchange="dtrange()"></p>

    function dtrange(){ 
var start = $("#from").datepicker("getDate"); //yyyy-mm-dd
var end = $("#to").datepicker("getDate"); //yyyy-mm-dd

while(start <= end){
    var mm = ((start.getMonth()+1)>=10)?(start.getMonth()+1):'0'+(start.getMonth()+1);
    var dd = ((start.getDate())>=10)? (start.getDate()) : '0' + (start.getDate());
    var yyyy = start.getFullYear();
    var date = dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yyyy; //yyyy-mm-dd

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += (date+'<br>'); 

    start = new Date(start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1)); //увеличиваем дату на 1

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции `dtrange` перед `while`

сделайте: `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '';`

А то поле `result` будет только дописывать значение в себя, без очистки

```
function dtrange(){
    var start = $("#from").datepicker("getDate"); //yyyy-mm-dd
    var end = $("#to").datepicker("getDate"); //yyyy-mm-dd
    var result = document.getElementById("result");

    result.innerHTML = '';
    while(start <= end){
        var mm = ((start.getMonth()+1)>=10)?(start.getMonth()+1):'0'+(start.getMonth()+1);
        var dd = ((start.getDate())>=10)? (start.getDate()) : '0' + (start.getDate());
        var yyyy = start.getFullYear();
        var date = dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yyyy; //yyyy-mm-dd

        result.innerHTML += (date+'<br>');

        start = new Date(start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1)); //увеличиваем дату на 1

    }
}
```